# Runtime.exec not working after the latest Java Update?

Tags: java, file, apk, decompiler

Here's my problem: I'm working on a program which decompiles an APK file. It was working. After the previous Java Update my application is giving me an exception.

[image]

Please help me.

UPDATE:

- New Java version - Version 7 Update 2
- Stack trace:

  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments
      at java.lang.ProcessImpl.isQuoted(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.ProcessImpl.getExecutablePath(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
      at ro.etrandafir.mate.PC.decompile.StartingPoint.execute(StartingPoint.java:146)
      at ro.etrandafir.mate.PC.decompile.StartingPoint.main(StartingPoint.java:25)
- Source code:

  ```
  try {
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"" + apktoolBat
              .getAbsolutePath() + "\" d -s " + fn);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line = null;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println("Apktool: " + line);
      }
  } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("ERROR: Could not use APKTOOL!");
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
  }
  ```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why won't you include the error message and a stack trace in you post directly?

Comment: It is in the screensho. Anyway, here I'm posting it right now.

Comment: Posting sources, error messages and traces in your post makes it easier for others to help you, because they don't have to check if links don't lead to unreliable sources, click links, load images, etc. It is also good practice, because your posting will not suffer from link rotting and thus is more helpful for other people in future.

Comment: None of Mediafire, Google Drive or Dropbox links will "die", I've putted the files in a folder called "DO NOT DELETE". Anyway, this program will be very useful if you want to decompile apk, it runs apktool, dex2jar and jad and puts the result is a single folder, resulting an eclipse project ready to be edited and recompiled (resources, xml, code etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has been changed in the new java release. See [oracles documentation of the feature change](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html#jruntime) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. And please don't downvote! I don't wanna be banned. I have only 18 reputation. And thank you again for the link, It really helped me.